# Python script not downloading files

Tags: python

I have the code below. It prints out the URL in the console. I'm having trouble figuring out how to get it to just download it instead of displaying it. I also want to be able to search for .mov file type. I'd rather have information on how to do this rather than it done for me. Any help is appreciated!

```
import urllib

def is_download_allowed():
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://10.1.1.27/config?action=get&paramid=eParamID_MediaState")
    response = f.read()
    if (response.find('"value":"1"') > -1):
        return True
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://10.1.1.27/config?action=set&paramid=eParamID_MediaState&value=1")

def download_clip():
    url = "http://10.1.1.27/media/SC1ATK26"
    print url

def is_not_download_allowed():
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://10.1.1.27/config?action=get&paramid=eParamID_MediaState")
    response = f.read()
    if (response.find('"value":"-1"') > 1):
        return True
    f = urllib.urlopen("http://10.1.1.27/config?action=set&paramid=eParamID_MediaState&value=1")

is_download_allowed()
download_clip()
is_not_download_allowed()
```

Comment: Your `download()` function doesn't call anything that accesses the internet, and even if it did, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Should I update my code with what I changed to get more direction? I have modified the code and it runs but nothing happens. I want to see if I am on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You say you don’t want a full solution so ...

Try urllib.urlretrieve

As commented already your download function is just printing a string.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. I was thinking of using that but wasn't sure if that would do it.